# How would one make it so this Personal Assistant is always in the background and also uses a wake work?

Tags: python

basically I'm experimenting with coding a personal assistant but am unsure as to how to make her run in the background and be woken by a wake word; currently I only can manually run her in Pycharm or other IDEs. Id like to know how to have it always running like cortana as opposed to just only running when i open an IDE and click 'run'

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from  time import ctime
import webbrowser
import time
import playsound
import os
import gtts
import random
from gtts import gTTS
import subprocess


r = sr.Recognizer()
#records your audio like a little creep ;)
def record_audio(ask = False):
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        if ask:
            vivian_speak(ask)

        audio = r.listen(source)
        voice_data = ""
        try:
            voice_data = r.recognize_google(audio)

        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            vivian_speak("Sorry, I couldn't hear you")
        except sr.RequestError:
            vivian_speak("Sorry, my speech API is currently offline. I apologize.")
        return voice_data
#this is just nerd shit to make the audio go from text to speech
def vivian_speak(audio_string):
    tts = gTTS(text=audio_string, lang='en')
    r = random.randint(1, 10000000)
    audio_file = 'audio-' + str(r) + '.mp3'
    tts.save(audio_file)
    playsound.playsound(audio_file)
    print(audio_string)
    os.remove(audio_file)
#this is how my beautiful robot baby speaks
def respond(voice_data):
    if 'road work ahead' in voice_data:
        vivian_speak('I sure hope it does')
    if 'League' in voice_data:
        vivian_speak('Opening League of Legends')
        subprocess.Popen(['C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\\LeagueClient.exe'])
    if 'what is your name' in voice_data:
        vivian_speak('My name is, Vivian.')
    if 'what time is it' in voice_data or 'what is the time' in voice_data:
        vivian_speak(ctime())
    if "search" in voice_data:
        search = record_audio("What should I search for?")
        url = 'https://google.com/search?q=' + search
        webbrowser.get().open(url)
        vivian_speak("Here are the results for " + search)
    if "find" in voice_data:
        location = record_audio("What would you like me to find?")
        url = 'https://google.nl/maps/place/' + location + "/&amp;"
        webbrowser.get().open(url)
        vivian_speak("Here is the location of " + location)
    if 'how are you' in voice_data:
        vivian_speak('I am doing well today! How about yourself?')
        voice_data = record_audio()
        if 'good' in voice_data or 'great' in voice_data or 'okay' in voice_data or 'alright' in voice_data:
            vivian_speak("I'm glad! What can I do for you?")

        if 'bad' in voice_data or 'horrible' in voice_data or 'eh' in voice_data or 'terrible' in voice_data:
            vivian_speak("I'm sorry to hear that. What can i do to change that?")

    if 'close' in voice_data or 'exit' in voice_data or 'stop' in voice_data or 'bye' in voice_data or 'goodbye' in voice_data or 'thank you' in voice_data:
        vivian_speak("happy to help")
        exit()



#this lets me run multiple commands in a row
time.sleep(1)
vivian_speak("Hello there. What can i do for you?")
while 1:
    voice_data = record_audio()
    print(voice_data)
    respond(voice_data)
```

Comment: really always running in the background is something you get from running things as a service/daemon - i.e. something that is launched on system startup and kept up by a system-level watchdog program that restarts your program when it stops.  On Linux, that'd be systemd, Windows has services and macos has its own launcher mechanism.  Before you get there, Jack's answer is quite appropriate, except that you'll have to launch it manually whenever you want to use it and restart if it fails.  And Jack's answer is way more appropriate until your program is totally stable and the way you want it.

Comment: definitely noted! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of clicking run in your IDE, you may want to run Python in the command line.

For example, you'd run:

```
python NameOfFile.py
```

This will keep running until the program exits, or you close the command window.

Comment: thank you a lot for this! really appreciate the help :)